# Como cerrar correctamente los Estados de Conexión y Stream Controllers en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, stream, programación-reactiva

**No consigo cerrar adecuadamente los Streams que abro en una de mis páginas del App.**

La situación es la siguiente: En una página del App tengo un reporte que suma el inventario disponible y en la otra página se pueden agregar cantidades al inventario o consumirlo (Formularios). Siempre que voy a la página de reportes y después a la página de Formularios, puedo observar en el debug que continúan haciéndose conexiones de estado y sumas del inventario, a pesar de que estoy en una página completamente diferente. Si al iniciar la aplicación voy directamente a Formularios sin pasar por el Reporte no sucede eso. Todo esto me hace pensar que no estoy cerrando correctamente los streams / estados. He revisado el código, pero no logro identificar lo que estoy haciendo mal.

El código de Reportes, es algo como esto:

```
    class ReportesPage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      @override
      _ReportesPageState createState() => _ReportesPageState();
    }
    
    Future<double>                    _sumaAlimento;
    
    class _ReportesPageState extends State<ReportesPage> {
    
      AlimentoBloc alimentoBloc             = new AlimentoBloc();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _sumaAlimento       = alimentoBloc.sumarAlimento(_prefs.idEmpresa); //Revisar esta suma
      }
    
    @override
      void dispose() {
        alimentoBloc.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      //
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            // extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
            appBar:               utils.appBarTransparente(context),
            body:                 _crearReportes(context),
            bottomNavigationBar:  utils.crearBottom(context, 1),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget _crearReportes(BuildContext context) {
        final _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 8,),
            Text('Inventario', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, 
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            _cargarInventario(context),
          ],
        ),
                      
      }
  _cargarInventario(BuildContext context) {

    double _inventario;

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _sumaAlimento, 
      // initialData: InitialData,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        print('Inventario ${snapshot.connectionState}');
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData){ 
          print(snapshot.data);
          _inventario = snapshot.data; //TODO: Cada que reinicia llega acá
          return Text('${_inventario.round()} Kgs', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, color: Colors.grey[700]));
        } else return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
              width: 20.0,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 1.0,)
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

En el patrón BLOC tengo lo siguiente...

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AlimentoBloc {
  final _sumaController = new BehaviorSubject<double>();
  final _alimentoProvider = new AlimentoProvider();
  Stream <double> get sumaStream => _sumaController.stream;


  Future<double> sumarAlimento(String idEmpresa) async {
      final sumaAlimento = await _alimentoProvider.sumarAlimento(idEmpresa);
      _sumaController.sink.add(sumaAlimento);
      return sumaAlimento;
  }

  dispose() {
    _sumaController?.close();
  }
}
```

Y dentro del Provider, obtengo la suma desde la base de datos con esta función...

```
Future<double> sumarAlimento(String idEmpresa) async {
  double _sumaInventario = 0.0;
  Query resp = db.child('--PATH--/alimento');
  return resp.once().then((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.value == null) return null;
      snapshot.value.forEach((id, item){
        final temp = AlimentoModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(item));
        _sumaInventario = _sumaInventario + temp.cantidad;
      });
      return _sumaInventario;
  }); 
}
```

Como pueden observar, uso dispose tanto en el BLOC como en la página de Reportes, sin embargo es como si simplemente el **dispose no funcionara.**

Los mensajes continuos que aparecen en el debug cada que entro a editar una caja de texto en páginas completamente diferentes a las de los reportes, lucen así...

I/flutter (26366): Inventario ConnectionState.done
I/flutter (26366): 394.3

Comment: Quizas no entra al metodo dispose del State, porque tu widget aún no ha sido sacado del arbol de widgets, estas seguro de eso?

Comment: Puedes tener razón. Puse un breakpoint en el dispose() y nunca pasó por esas líneas. Cómo hago para asegurar que se salga del arbol de widgets?

Comment: Tendrias que hacer un Navigator pop, pero no se como estas mostrando y cerrando vistas, deberias mostrar tu interfaz mediante un gif para tener maa contexto.

Comment: Entro y salgo de las vistas mediante un BottomNavigationBar que hace un llamado del tipo Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'reportes') según el index que sea tapped

Comment: Hmm cuando retrocedes de la vista de reportes deberia sacarla del widget tree (llamar a dispose)  a menos q use stack y los mantenga, es raro, un gif o video ayudaria mas

Comment: Buen punto... en efecto cuando aplico el botón retroceder (back), si va al dispose. Cuando paso de un tap al otro dentro del Bottom no. No sé si sirva, pero el Bottom lo estoy accediendo desde una página de Utils compartida para toda el App... es el utils.crearBottom que aparece en el código

Comment: Bueno ya tienes la respuesta, si los estas cerrando bien solo cuando llamas a dispose, es decir lo sacas del widgt tree, sino pues no

Comment: Cómo me aseguro que cuando pase de un Tap a otro, en efecto salga del Widget Tree?

Comment: No tengo idea porq no veo tu interfaz de usuario, es imposible saberlo, para q un widget salga del widget tree es cuando haz hecho back, o cuando has llamado a navigator.pop dentro del mismo widget

Comment: Gracias Diego... Fueron muy útiles tus preguntas. Simplemente cambié el pushNamed que te mencioné del Bottom por un pushReplacementNamed y funcionó correctamente.

Comment: Genial, ahí ya estás sacandolo del widget tree porq lo reemplaza, bien. Siguenme en youtube para ver cosas mas avanzadas de flutter youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: Ok, dale. No se si quieras incluir la respuesta para que quede cerrado el caso

Comment: ahora lo hago :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás cerrando el `StreamController` de manera correcta, el problema es que no estás llamando al método `dispose` del State, por lo tanto el `dispose` del bloc tampoco es llamado.

Al hacer `Navigator.pushNamed` estás insertando otro widget en el widget tree, más no reemplazando el anterior, por lo tanto `dispose` nunca es llamado.

Para solucionarlo,  solo cambia `Navigator.pushNamed` por `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed` y listo.